# Number of SPO sites causing issue with Get-SPOSite

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have been using these few lines in a SPO site creation script for a while, to ensure a site doesn't exist already:

```
# Verify if site of same name already exists in SharePoint Online
$siteAlreadyExists = Get-SPOSite | Where-Object{$_.url -eq $url}

# If it does, stop the script
if ($null -ne $siteAlreadyExists) {
    Write-Host "Site already exists" -ForegroundColor Red
    Break new-SPOnlineSite
}

else{
    # Otherwise, create the site
    Write-Host "Creating $($url)"
    New-SPOSite -Url $url -title $title -Owner $userName -StorageQuota $storageQuota -NoWait -Template $template
}
```

Now, presumably because we have so many sites, I see this error:

> WARNING: More results were found but were not returned.  Use '-Limit
>   ALL' to return all possible results.

However, even when adding -Limit ALL to the appropriate line...

```
$siteAlreadyExists = Get-SPOSite -Limit ALL | Where-Object{$_.url -eq $url}
```

...the error remains.

Does anyone understand why or how to fix it please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to load all site collections and then look for one particular site matching the URL. Instead you can use '-Identity' parameter along with the site collection URL you need to check to find out the existence.

Example: Get-SPOSite -Identity https://contoso.sharepoint.com

You can update your code like below:

```
# Verify if site of same name already exists in SharePoint Online
$siteAlreadyExists = Get-SPOSite -Identity $url

# If it does, stop the script
if ($null -ne $siteAlreadyExists) {
    Write-Host "Site already exists" -ForegroundColor Red
    ...
}
```

[image]

As per the comment, I understand the code is failing when site is not present. So, I have wrapped the checking inside a try-catch block, like below:

```
try {
    $siteAlreadyExists = Get-SPOSite -Identity $url

    if ($null -ne $siteAlreadyExists) {
        Write-Host "Site already exists" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
catch {
    Write-Host "Site already exists" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

This code should solve that problem as well.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that leaves me with:

Get-SPOSite : Cannot get site https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/Testy-Test.
At C:\SPOScripts\New-ExternalSPOSite - NEW.ps1:51 char:22
+ $siteAlreadyExists = Get-SPOSite -Identity $url
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-SPOSite], ServerException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException,Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.GetSite

Comment: @TomUrwin Thanks for pointing out the error. Please check the updated code in my answer. It should solve your problem. Please mark it as answer if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately that still fails to continue when $url is empty and you want the script to continue:

Get-SPOSite : Cannot get site https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/Tomu-Test

I think this is why I originally used the Where-Object approach.

Any other ideas appreciated.

Comment: @TomUrwin I'm sure you can add a if condition to check if $url is empty or null before using it in the Get-SPOSite command.

Comment: Thanks, but the point is this has been working fine the way it was for months until the site list got too long.

Comment: OK in the end I have managed to make a combination of try, catch and ifs work. Thanks again

Comment: @TomUrwin it's good to know that you now have a working solution :)